# Protractor - Changing the target window

Tags: protractor

I need my automation to open new tab for each describe tests.
To do so, I open a new chrome tab in the beginning of each describe, enter the wanted URL, switching back to the first tab and closes him.

```
openNewTab()
switchTab()
browser.close()
```

It works fine, but when I run it - it says that "no such window target window already closed" after it closes the first chrome tab.
I assume that it happens because the automation recognize only the first chrome tab as the "target window" (and there is the session that runs).

How can I handle it?

Comment: It may be because of the driver focus. Can you share the cod of `openNewTab()` and `switchTab()`

Comment: how can  I change the driver focus?

Comment: share the code for the functions you have used.